# How to attach a client certificate to HttpClient in .NET Core in Linux?

Tags: c#, linux, ssl, .net-core

I am creating a console application in .NET Core that makes a call to an internal web API.  The internal API requires a client certificate be attached to a request.  The console application is to be installed and run on Linux, specifically RHEL7.  The console application is currently using .NET core 3.1, although I was having the same problem with .NET core 2.2.  I am developing the console application on Windows 10.

The issue I am having is that when the application runs from RHEL, the request fails and the API server is returning a 403.7 Forbidden response, implying that the client certificate is not being included.  I can run the application and connect successfully to the web API from Windows 10.  I can also run the application and connect successfully from the Ubuntu WSL on Windows 10.

I have an implementation of `HttpClient` with a custom `HttpClientHandler` like this:

```
public class MyClient : HttpClient {
        public MyClient() : base(getRequestHandler()) {         
        }
        private static HttpClientHandler getRequestHandler() {
            try {
                var requestHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
                X509Certificate2 certificate = null;

                /* Get Certificate */
                var pathToPfx = string.Empty;
                if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["certificateFileName"] != null) {
                    pathToPfx = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["certificateFileName"].ToString();
                }
                var pfxPassword = string.Empty;
                if(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["certificatePassword"] != null) {
                    pfxPassword = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["certificatePassword"].ToString();
                }

                // load certificate
                log.Debug($"Loading certificate from {pathToPfx}");
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(pfxPassword)) {
                    certificate = new X509Certificate2(pathToPfx, pfxPassword);
                } else {
                    certificate = new X509Certificate2(pathToPfx);
                }

                // add certificate to request
                if (certificate != null) {
                    requestHandler.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate);
                }

                return requestHandler;
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                log.Error(ex, ex.Message);
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```

My intent is to be able to attach a specified certificate to the request, but to not have to rely on a cert store since I'm not sure what level of support that has on Linux.  It seemed like I should be able to independently attach a specified certificate file. My understanding is that the client certificate needs the private key to work, and on Windows that come in the form of a .pfx file and password, but on Linux it can be a single b64 encoded cert file as long as it has both public and private keys.

On Windows I have a .pfx certificate file I can use to connect to the API.  If I point the application to that file, and include the password, everything works as expected.  But I couldn't use the .pfx file from within Linux, so I used openSSL (on WSL) to separately parse out the certificate and private key from the .pfx file.  I then combined those two pieces into a single Linux-compatible certificate file "mycert.cer":

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
...key data...
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...cert data...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Referencing that file, on WSL I can run the application and it will successfully connect to the API.  I can also run openSSL against the cert file and it appears to come back valid.

On the RHEL system, I can run curl against the API url, passing in the new cert, like this:
`curl -v --cert mycert.cer 'https://my.internal.server/url'`
and it will come back successfully.
But when the web request is made from the console app, running in RHEL, I get the 403 Forbidden response referenced above.

How should I be attaching the client certificate to the HttpClient in a manner that will work when running on Windows or on Linux? Am I missing something with how certificates work on Linux where it's not actually sending the private key when run from RHEL even though it's in the file?  I'd like to know if I'm trying to chase down some environmental problem in the RHEL system I'm using, or if I'm just doing something wrong in my code.

Thanks for any help,

Comment: I too have the exact same problem. Any solution you found ?

Comment: @Sai I ended up sticking with using a .pfx and corresponding password; I never could get just a plain PEM that included the private key to work. I think part of my problem was I couldn't just take a pfx file from my Windows machine and use that on linux. I engaged our sysadmins and they generated a cert from our AD server, and built up a p12 with password on linux, and I pass the cert path and password to my service. I'd like to reproduce a standalone example and submit to github to troubleshoot it further.

Comment: Yes i think the best is to use .pfx. Also I got it to work using .pfx and http client inside a linux container.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64822993/net-core-docker-how-to-access-pfx-certificate-in-code-with-httpclient-trying-t/64851862#64851862
If you still need help let me know .

Comment: Do you get any work around. I am facing the same issue. All working perfect at local machine but not at linux server.

Comment: @sina_Islam as noted above I still ended up including a .pfx cert file on the file system and getting the password via settings. I did eventually find some discussion here (https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/27658) that implies there might be a way to use a “cert store” in linux to reference certificates, but I haven’t tried that yet.

Comment: @PeterTirrell, I got a workaround. You can see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73189689/the-ssl-connection-could-not-be-established-see-inner-exception-for-post-req/73201819#73201819. it is working perfectly.